# Is there a word or phrase for an obvious and unhelpful remark?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example, if after you touch a hot pan and pull your hand away, someone says "Careful, that's hot.".  Or if you dropped something and are fully aware of it, "You dropped something."

Is there a word or phrase that defines remarks that are either obvious or unhelpful, or more likely both?

Besides the obvious "unhelpful", that is.  I'm wondering if there is a more proper term that's applied to such remarks.

Edit:
The linked duplicate question is close, but not exactly what I'm asking.  And I realize I may not be phrasing it correctly, or that what I'm trying to ask just doesn't have a good answer.

"Platitude" and "bromide" may be the closest matching terms, and I'd be OK with that.

I was just wondering about the specific situations where *something happens* and someone says that *it happened*.  A statement that is unnecessary since the person they are talking to already knows.